# Wordpress Local to Live and The Missing Widgets!

Tags: widgets, sidebar, migration

I have just finished my local dev of a wordpress woo theme for a client which has extensive sidebar customization and widgets.

Ive done a full mysql export and import via phpmyadmin. However when I go to the demo site there are no widgets assigned to the sidebars that are registered using traditional wordpress methods and the woo theme sidebar manager has no sidebars.

Im a little confused!

Comment: @user1774: Stupid thing to check, but you made sure to also upload the `wp-content/plugins` directory, so all extra plugins that might define widgets are available too?

Answer (score 1):

Did you find/replace URLs in the database after you moved it to the live server? If not, you still have localhost URLs as opposed to mydomain.com in the database and that may be the cause.

If you did change URLs, use the Woo Themes functions of export/import of theme settings.